# Simple linking test to MKL libraries fails

Tags: c++, intel-mkl

I wanted to test my MKL installation by compiling a simple program with the library:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <mkl.h>

int main(void)
{
        std::cout << "Hello World\n";
        return 0;
}
```

Now by using the MKL Link Line Advisor, I get the following compilation line:

```
g++ -DMKL_ILP64 -m64 -I${MKLROOT}/include test.cpp -L${MKLROOT}/lib/intel64 -Wl,--no-as-needed -lmkl_intel_ilp64 -lmkl_gnu_thread -lmkl_core -lgomp -lpthread -lm -ldl -o test
```

with using GCC-6.3.0 and `MKLROOT` set to the correct path. But when compiling, I get

```
/home/rolandar/local_opt/intel/mkl/lib/intel64/libmkl_gnu_thread.so: error: undefined reference to 'fopen'
/home/rolandar/local_opt/intel/mkl/lib/intel64/libmkl_gnu_thread.so: error: undefined reference to 'fflush'
/home/rolandar/local_opt/intel/mkl/lib/intel64/libmkl_gnu_thread.so: error: undefined reference to 'free'
/home/rolandar/local_opt/intel/mkl/lib/intel64/libmkl_intel_ilp64.so: error: undefined reference to 'exit'
/home/rolandar/local_opt/intel/mkl/lib/intel64/libmkl_intel_ilp64.so: error: undefined reference to 'memset'
/home/rolandar/local_opt/intel/mkl/lib/intel64/libmkl_gnu_thread.so: error: undefined reference to 'strcasecmp'
/home/rolandar/local_opt/intel/mkl/lib/intel64/libmkl_gnu_thread.so: error: undefined reference to 'fclose'
/home/rolandar/local_opt/intel/mkl/lib/intel64/libmkl_gnu_thread.so: error: undefined reference to 'syscall'
/home/rolandar/local_opt/intel/mkl/lib/intel64/libmkl_gnu_thread.so: error: undefined reference to 'strtol'
/home/rolandar/local_opt/intel/mkl/lib/intel64/libmkl_gnu_thread.so: error: undefined reference to 'malloc'
/home/rolandar/local_opt/intel/mkl/lib/intel64/libmkl_gnu_thread.so: error: undefined reference to 'strcmp'
/home/rolandar/local_opt/intel/mkl/lib/intel64/libmkl_core.so: error: undefined reference to 'calloc'
/home/rolandar/local_opt/intel/mkl/lib/intel64/libmkl_core.so: error: undefined reference to 'getenv'
/home/rolandar/local_opt/intel/mkl/lib/intel64/libmkl_core.so: error: undefined reference to 'fwrite'
/home/rolandar/local_opt/intel/mkl/lib/intel64/libmkl_core.so: error: undefined reference to '__ctype_b_loc'
/home/rolandar/local_opt/intel/mkl/lib/intel64/libmkl_core.so: error: undefined reference to 'realloc'
/home/rolandar/local_opt/intel/mkl/lib/intel64/libmkl_core.so: error: undefined reference to 'vfprintf'
/home/rolandar/local_opt/intel/mkl/lib/intel64/libmkl_core.so: error: undefined reference to 'ceil'
/home/rolandar/local_opt/intel/mkl/lib/intel64/libmkl_core.so: error: undefined reference to 'gettimeofday'
/home/rolandar/local_opt/intel/mkl/lib/intel64/libmkl_core.so: error: undefined reference to 'strtoul'
/home/rolandar/local_opt/intel/mkl/lib/intel64/libmkl_core.so: error: undefined reference to 'fopen64'
/home/rolandar/local_opt/intel/mkl/lib/intel64/libmkl_core.so: error: undefined reference to 'strtod'
/home/rolandar/local_opt/intel/mkl/lib/intel64/libmkl_core.so: error: undefined reference to 'stdout'
/home/rolandar/local_opt/intel/mkl/lib/intel64/libmkl_core.so: error: undefined reference to 'sched_yield'
/home/rolandar/local_opt/intel/mkl/lib/intel64/libmkl_core.so: error: undefined reference to 'mmap'
/home/rolandar/local_opt/intel/mkl/lib/intel64/libmkl_core.so: error: undefined reference to 'fread'
/home/rolandar/local_opt/intel/mkl/lib/intel64/libmkl_core.so: error: undefined reference to 'stderr'
/home/rolandar/local_opt/intel/mkl/lib/intel64/libmkl_core.so: error: undefined reference to 'mprotect'
/home/rolandar/local_opt/intel/mkl/lib/intel64/libmkl_core.so: error: undefined reference to 'qsort'
/home/rolandar/local_opt/intel/mkl/lib/intel64/libmkl_core.so: error: undefined reference to 'munmap'
/home/rolandar/local_opt/intel/mkl/lib/intel64/libmkl_core.so: error: undefined reference to 'getuid'
/home/rolandar/local_opt/intel/mkl/lib/intel64/libmkl_core.so: error: undefined reference to 'vsnprintf'
/home/rolandar/local_opt/intel/mkl/lib/intel64/libmkl_core.so: error: undefined reference to 'strchr'
/home/rolandar/local_opt/intel/mkl/lib/intel64/libmkl_core.so: error: undefined reference to 'isspace'
/home/rolandar/local_opt/intel/mkl/lib/intel64/libmkl_core.so: error: undefined reference to 'strdup'
```

Is my MKL-installation broken? Or did I forget something else?

Answer (score 0):

Could you try this?

```
-L${MKLROOT}/lib/intel64 Wl,--no-as-needed -lmkl_rt -lpthread -lm -ldl
```

Comment: No change, unfortunately

Comment: terribly sorry you also will need to remove `-DMKL_ILP64`

Comment: Tested both removal and change to `-DMKL_LP64`, but no change

Comment: wt*? do you have a little detail about gcc version, linux version, mkl version etc

Comment: GCC is 6.3.0, Linux is `Linux version 3.10.0-327.36.3.el7.x86_64`, and MKL is most recent from 2017

Comment: Blast! Looks just right. WT*? I just updated the answer. Does that solve it for you?

Comment: Your edit generates similar errors, but for mkl_rt. I will try to reinstall the mkl library now...

Comment: I'm not too optimistic, that a reinstall is going anywhere. Really sorry, that I couldn't help. :(

Comment: Found the problem: When removing the option `-ldl`, it works perfectly

Comment: So the version I put up or both?

Comment: All versions, strangely

Answer (score 0):

When removing the option `-ldl`, it works, but I have no explanation, why.